# Drupal 8 - Where do I change interface.default to sparkpost_mail

Tags: drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 site, and I have just installed the Sparkpost module (https://www.drupal.org/project/sparkpost).

On the settings screen in Drupal for this module I'm seeing the following message;

```
You seem to be using php_mail as your mail system instead of sparkpost_mail. If this is not on purpose, you should change the configration for interface.default in system.mail to sparkpost_mail.
```

Where do I change this setting as I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in order to change the default mail system, I needed to install the Mail System Drupal 8 Module, then use it to change the system wide settings.